# How do I get username and enrollment code for a fresh ejbca setup?

Tags: certificate, ejbca, jscep, openscep

I am running EJBCA in virtualbox as mentioned at https://ejbca.org/download.html . When I try to "Create Browser Certificate" or "Create certificate from CSR", it is asking for

Username

and

Enrollment code

[image]

Where do I get the username and the enrollment code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an end entity before (you must be connected to the administration GUI, and already  imported the p12 file in your browser)

You can follow the three follwing link to create an end entity :

- Create a Certificate Profile : https://www.ejbca.org/docs/Create_a_Certificate_Profile_for_SSL_Servers.html
- Create an End Entity Profile : 
  https://www.ejbca.org/docs/Create_an_End_Entity_Profile_for_SSL_Servers.html
- Issue New Server Certificate : 
  https://www.ejbca.org/docs/Issue_a_New_Server_Certificate_from_a_CSR.html

In this last step that you will define your username and password.